# Can I add on the webpage, data that I get from a Highcharts function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I would like to add some text to my canvas, on top of the legend and the other text that is already implemented in Highcharts; so I was thinking to add some elements to the page on which I have the chart container.

Now I am not sure if I can do so, since the data that I require needs to come from the data that Highcharts uses to build the charts (CSV files), like average, min-max and so on.

IS there an easy way to do so; or should I just add a different script in my page, written in pure JS, that retrieve the data and present it?

Or can I just add these info directly on the canvas? I am still new to HC, so I am not sure what it can do and such.

Answer (score 1):

In general, once you loaded file, you can create chart and add extra info on a page, snippet:

```
$.get(url, function(data){ 
    createChart(data);
    addExtraInfoToThePage(data);
});
```

Now you can write this two functions and what you want.

You have also another solution, after you created chart you can add info th the page, snippet:

```
$.get(url, function(data){ 
    // parse CSV file ...
    $("#contianer").highcharts({
        // set options, like series etc.
    }, function(chart) {
        // add info like min/max/avg to the page here
        // you have access to the series like:
        // chart.series[index]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export the file as a png, svg, jpeg or pdf and then you just include it using img src=whatever

To enable exporting you will need a script that can be downloaded on the [Highcharts page](http://code.highcharts.com/)

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

You can also use a library called [canvg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/). This can be used as a way of exporting charts without involving any server side conversion. Since Highcharts is drawn in SVG, we need a way to convert it to a HTML5 canvas. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/R6j9F/)

There are a number of online tools that will convert your csv to a html table including [textfixer](http://www.textfixer.com/html/csv-convert-table.php)

There is a javascript file that will do it posted [here](http://www.winscripter.com/WSH/FileIO/76.aspx)

[Reference](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly. The issue is not exporting the chart file; but get data that I have already used to plot the graph, and put it on a webpage, as plain text. The idea is that since I have already the data extracted with the $.get() for HC, I can also display interesting stats like the average or min-max values in that series. The chart is fine as is, I just want to put more data on the page that render the chart. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can access the data you need is using the chart API calls . Once the chart has been rendered, you can get at it's series data using chart.series[0].data, or even the min/max values using chart.yaxis[0].getExtremes().

```
var yMax = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax;
var yMin = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMin;
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.data

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes

You just need to make sure that the chart is fully created before access this data. One place to do this in in the load event:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load.

```
$(function () {
// create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(event) {
                alert (this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().dataMax);
            }
        }        
    },
    xAxis: {
    },

    series: [{
        animation: false,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]     
    }]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtckL/

Comment: Thanks Steve. Is there a place where the order of the functions is explained? I am having hard time figuring out when things happens, especially when I need to load data from external files...know what is called and in which order, helps a lot in planning where to put each function. Thanks!